# Repeat method with OnActivityResult every X seconds

Tags: java, android, repeat, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I have a method that takes a picture and then in the onActivityResult passes to another activity for subsequent analysis of the picture. So far so good.

My problem is that when I use a handler to repeat the process every 10 sec, the method is called but it will only take photos automatically without passing to the other activity. My guess is that when the method is called again automatically the onActivityResult is never called. Does anybody have a clue of which could may be be the problem?

```
takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    TakePhoto();
        }
    });

private void TakePhoto() {
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagepath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
    File newFile = new File(imagepath, ".jpg");
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        newFile.delete();
    }else {
        newFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
    }
    selectedPhotoPath = getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", newFile);

startActivityForResult(captureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedPhotoPath);
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable(KEY_BITMAP, selectedPhotoPath);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TakePhoto();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    },10000);    
}
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!!! Thanks

Comment: `bundle.putParcelable(KEY_BITMAP, selectedPhotoPath);` there is zero guarantee that this won't crash on API 23+ because of exceeding bundle transaction limit.

Comment: can you increase the delay from 10 secs to 30 secs

Comment: I have done it even for more; 60 sec but nothing changes.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Repeat the whole process/image analysis automatically